# ManyChat GetSubscriberInfo API r in a bulk

Tags: r, facebook, api

Trying to get subscribers info via API in ManyChat
Have a sample of user ids: 3110802792326767 2222758544512270 2756919657701551

Coerced it to integer64 using fread

```
dt <- fread("sample.csv")
> str(dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ subscriber_id:integer64 3110802792326767 2222758544512270 2756919657701551 
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

my codes:

```
lapply(seq_along(dt$subscriber_id), function(x){
  query_param = list(subscriber_id = dt[(x),])
  GET(url = "https://api.manychat.com/fb/subscriber/getInfo", query = query_param,
      accept_json(),
      add_headers(Authorization = 'Bearer my_bearer'))
})
```

```
lapply(seq_along(dt$subscriber_id), function(x){
  GET(url = "https://api.manychat.com/fb/subscriber/getInfo?subscriber_id=as.list(dt[x,])",
                  accept_json(),
                  add_headers(Authorization = 'Bearer my_bearer'))
})
```

```
lapply(seq_along(dt$subscriber_id), function(x){
  query_param = list(subscriber_id = dt[as.integer64(x),])
  GET(url = "https://api.manychat.com/fb/subscriber/getInfo", query = query_param,
      accept_json(),
      add_headers(Authorization = 'Bearer my_bearer'))
})
```

Getting an error 400, cause Response looks like this

```
[[1]]
Response [https://api.manychat.com/fb/subscriber/getInfo?subscriber_id=1.53694079067568e-308]
  Date: 2019-12-26 10:20
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 117 B


[[2]]
Response [https://api.manychat.com/fb/subscriber/getInfo?subscriber_id=1.0981886358436e-308]
  Date: 2019-12-26 10:20
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 117 B


[[3]]
Response [https://api.manychat.com/fb/subscriber/getInfo?subscriber_id=1.36209929121475e-308]
  Date: 2019-12-26 10:20
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 117 B
```

All my ids coerced to numeric. Why? And how do I deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it doesn't work with column in data.table or data.frame, but when we put a vector it works. Like this

```
dt <- fread("sample.csv")
subs <- dt$subscribers_id
lapply(seq_along(dt$subscriber_id), function(x){
  query_param = list(subscriber_id = subs[x])
  GET(url = "https://api.manychat.com/fb/subscriber/getInfo", query = query_param,
      accept_json(),
      add_headers(Authorization = 'Bearer my_bearer'))
})
```